# Python async return coroutine (difference between returning variable with awaitable object and coroutine object directly)

Tags: python, asynchronous

I had a problem with my asynchronous code and I noticed a subtle quirk: if I store the awaitable object in a variable, the code will return a normal object, but if I return the awaitable object directly, the code will return a coroutine (which I don't know how to convert to a normal object ). What is the difference between the two approaches (returning a variable and an object directly)?

```
async def load_page(url: str):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url=url) as resp:
            if 200 <= resp.status <= 299:
                result = await resp.text()
                #  return resp.text() # This code will return coroutine
                #  return result  # This code will be return regular object 


async def main():
    tasks = []
    url = 'http://example.com'
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(load_page(url=url,)))
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

P.S. a secondary question is can I avoid using `asyncio.create_task`?

Comment: Just omit `create_task`…?! `return await load_page(...)` should work just fine.